# python how to collect a specific file from a list of folders and save

Tags: python, file, file-io

I have many folders in a master folder as given below. Each folder contains a .JPG file. I would like to extract all these files and store them in this master folder.

[image]

Inside each folder 
[image]

My present code:

```
import os
import glob 

os.chdir('Master folder')
extension = 'JPG'
jpg_files= [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]
```

This did not work.

Comment: Is the list `jpg_files` giving all of the jpg files as expected?

Comment: Can JPG files in different folders have the same name?

Comment: @timgeb No. They have different names. But each folder has on `JPG` file only. So, I believe, no need to worry about the file name.

Answer (score 3):

To find the images in your tree, I would use os.walk.  Below you can find a complete example to 'find and move' function that move all the files to your given path, and create a new filename for duplicate filenames.

The simple 'find and replace' function will also check with function `add_index_to_filepath` whether or not the file already exists, add an index (n) to the path.  For example:  if `image.jpg` would exists, it turns the next one into turn into `image (1).jpg` and the following one into `image (2).jpg` and so on.

```
import os
import re
import shutil

def add_index_to_filepath(path):
    '''
    Check if a file exists, and append '(n)' if true.
    '''
    # If the past exists, go adjust it
    if os.path.exists(path):
        # pull apart your path and filenames
        folder, file = os.path.split(path)
        filename, extension = os.path.splitext(file)

        # discover the current index, and correct filename
        try:
            regex = re.compile(r'\(([0-9]*)\)$')
            findex = regex.findall(filename)[0]
            filename = regex.sub('({})'.format(int(findex) + 1), filename)
        except IndexError:
            filename = filename + ' (1)'

        # Glue your path back together.
        new_path = os.path.join(folder, '{}{}'.format(filename, extension))

        # Recursivly call your function, go keep verifying if it exists.
        return add_index_to_filepath(new_path)

    return path


def find_and_move_files(path, extension_list):
    '''
    Walk through a given path and move the files from the sub-dir to the path.
    Upper-and lower-case are ignored.  Duplicates get a new filename.
    '''
    files_moved = []

    # First walk through the path, to list all files.
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path, topdown=False):
        for file in files:
            # Is your extension wanted?
            extension = os.path.splitext(file)[-1].lower()
            if extension in extension_list:
                # Perpare your old an new path, and move
                old_path = os.path.join(root, file)
                new_path = add_index_to_filepath(os.path.join(path, file))

                if new_path in files_moved:
                    shutil.move(old_path, new_path)

                # Lets keep track of what we moved to return it in the end
                files_moved.append(new_path)

    return files_moved

path = '.'  # your filepath for the  master-folder
extensions = ['.jpg', '.jpeg']  # There are some variations of a jpeg-file extension.
found_files = find_and_move_files(path, extensions)
```

Comment: Consider using `os.path.splitext`.

Comment: Nice idea.  Answer adjusted.

Comment: @timgeb, I added some checking.  Any suggestions on how to improve the index added to the filename?

Comment: I tend to cheat in those situations and prefix filenames with the SHA-1 hash of the path to the file's directory (`hashlib.sha1(root.encode('utf-8')).digest().hex()`). Assumes you are OK with a filename clash every couple million years :)

Comment: I decided to have a stab at using regex to fix the file-index issue.  I believe this concludes the question.  Happy to hear of any more adjustments to make this a better example.